# Getting count of Azure service bus using python

Tags: python, azure, powershell, azureservicebus, servicebus

I want to know there are too many service bus messages in my queue and if need be replay(dead-lettered messages) them. I am currently able to peek and replay the messages but I have no clue on how to get the active/dead-lettered-message count.
I'm basically looking for the python equivalent of this powershell command.

```
az servicebus queue show --resource-group myresourcegroup \
    --namespace-name mynamespace \
    --name myqueue \
    --query countDetails
```

There's documentation for this on powershell but I wasn't able to find anything for python. Can someone. Can someone kindly help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Service Bus Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/).

First get the properties of a queue using get_queue method which will contain property called message_count which will give you the count of messages.

```
queue = bus_service.get_queue('queue1')
print queue.message_count
```

Comment: I don't find the `get_queue` method anywhere. Can you kindly help with the same? 
I see a `get_queue_sender()`

Comment: The `get_queue` method is on the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` under the `azure.servicebus.management` namespace. You can find the total message count in the queue by following this sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/1709ec7898c87e4369f5324302f274f254857dc3/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/mgmt_queue.py#L72.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add as a comment, other answer is correct wrt Azure Service Bus Python SDK however code is slightly different

Sample code:

```
with azure.servicebus.management.ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) as client:
 print(client.get_queue_runtime_properties(QUEUE_NAME).active_message_count)
```

Key part is using the get_queue_runtime_properties and not just get_queue

(May be the case that the SDK has updated since)

Hope this helps someone!